# Finding xpath using Selenium java

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have this html tree:

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4ns" data-testid="test-modal"></div>
<div class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="test-icon">
<div class="css-1dbjc4n"><div class="css-1dbjc4n"</div><div class="css-1dbjc4n r- 
1wbh5a2 r-1peese0 r-6uxfom r-mbgqwd r-11c0sde r-1udh08x">
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao ">This item is not yet available</div>
```

I am trying to locate the text "This item is not yet available".

This is my xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@data-testid, 'test-modal-container')"//contains(text(),This item is not yet available));
private WebElement itemComingSoonalert;
```

I am getting no such element present exception, can anyone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='test-icon']/descendant::div[@dir='auto']");
private WebElement itemComingSoonalert;
```

or as request by OP :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='test-icon']/descendant::div[@dir='auto' and text()='This item is not yet available']");
private WebElement itemComingSoonalert;
```

Comment: I need to make it specific that's why need the text to identify.